# Mongoid self reference collection has_many not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Can't work out why this is not working

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

class Student < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ....
  has_one :parent , class_name: "Parent", inverse_of: :children

class Parent < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ....
  has_many :children, class_name: "Student", inverse_of: :parent
```

When I try to setup the parent/child relationship via

```
jane = Student.create!(name: "Jane")
janesParent = Parent.new(name: "Jenny")
janesParent.children.push(jane)
janesParent.save!
```

I get this error

```
  When adding a(n) Student to Parent#children, Mongoid could not determine the    
  inverse foreign key to set. The attempted key was 'parent_id'.
```

What have I done wrong?

P.S I don't want to embed these want to store the id's if applicable types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is 1-N relation, change `Student` model relation to

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Parent", inverse_of: :children
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried and `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation ?

Comment: Yup that works. However I wanted to model one Parent has many children and a child has Only one Parent. i.e 1....N relationship